# Bash - how can I reference a file as a variable?

Tags: bash

I am using a script to generate a file with the current date appended, then exporting that file to Amazon S3. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#python script that exports file in the form of "myfile{current date}.csv" to home directory
#example: myfile20150316.csv
python some_script.py

#recreate file name exported by some_script.py and save as a variable
now=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
file_name="myfile"
file_ext=".csv"
_file="$file_name$now$file_ext"

#export to file created by python to S3
s3cmd put $_file S3://myS3/bucket/$_file
```

The file is created by the python script and exported to my home directory, but the file is not exported to S3. My assumption is that I am incorrectly referencing the file in my `s3cmd` command.

This is not an S3 question. In a generic sense, how should I reference variables that contain file names to be able to use them in subsequent commands?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This looks fine but I don't know `s3cmd` command

Comment: What exactly is failing here? Is the `s3cmd` failing to put the file? Is the python script creating the file in some directory other than the current one?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the 'dot' separating the file name from the file extension.  If it were me, I'd have the python script print out the name of the file it creates and then just capture that so you don't have to recreate the filename:  `file="$(python myscript.py)"`

Comment: @Etan - the python script works fine and the file it written to the home directory. I have used the `s3cmd` command to put the file to S3 manually. I am just trying to do it in a bash script to run cron on it.

Comment: @nathan - I am using `file_ext=".csv"` for the file extension. the dot is there unless there is something else you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, but are you **in** "the home directory" when the script runs? Because if not then the path to the file is incorrect (and a cron job may very well not be in that directory).

Comment: In general, to reference a file by variable do you just use `x://location/of/file/$file_variable`?

Comment: yes, i am in the home directory and the cron job is set to the home directory. I have used the `s3cmd` command manually to send the file as well as set up a cron job to send the file using an explicit file name in the script.